# Comment syntax history

Tags: tcl

In early Tcl versions, was the comment command (`#anything`) treated exactly as a normal command (parsed) with the only exception that the arguments weren't sent anywhere? So you could do this...

```
% # {
  comment
}
```

...but not this:

```
% # remember to initialize $width here
can't read "width": no such variable
% # a comment [with brackets] here
invalid command name "with"
```

In what version(s) did it change to completely ignore everything after the # character to the end of line?

Answer (score 2):

The oldest released version of Tcl on sourceforge is [2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/Tcl%202.1/).  From the manpage in that tarball:

> #### COMMENTS
>
> If the first non-blank character in a command is `#`, then everything
>   from the `#` up through the next newline character is treated as
>   a comment and ignored.

So; no, for all practical purposes, comments are and have always been special syntax, not a regular tcl command.

**Edit,** re some comments (meta-comments?)

one of the reasons why comments *aren't* regular commands is because it provides an easy out for matching curly braces when you *don't* want them to match.  Suppose you wanted to write a proc that prints a single close brace.

```
proc writeBrace {} {
    puts "}"
}
```

unfortunately, the braces are no longer matched, and tcl sees, as the body of the proc `puts "`, since thats whats between the open brace and the *matching* close brace.  the fix is easy:

```
proc writeBrace {} {
    # match the brace below: {
    puts "}"
}
```

now, the number of open and close braces is matched in the proc body.  remember, braces are matched *before* tcl tries to parse a proc body, it's just a string during argument parsing, not tcl code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I've gotten errors with brackets in comments. Probably on some Mac OS version of Tcl about 10-15 years ago. I started to use only normal characters in comments after that.

Comment: @potrzebie - I know I've encountered that issue; and my company has always used Tcl 8.0.5 (1999).

Comment: You don't need comments for that. Just use `puts "\}"`. There are 4 + 1 things that have special meaning inside a curly brace quote: `{`, `}`, `\{`, `\}` and finally the line continuation sequence `\<line break><whitespace>`, which is parsed in a pre-pass so {} won't even see it (and therefore can't quote it).

Answer (score 0):

The rules do not state that every character after # is ignored, its a little bit more tricky than that.

This page on the Tcl'ers wiki explains the pitfalls of comment syntax in depth, so i won't repeat all of this here:
http://wiki.tcl.tk/462

Basically its an order of evaluation issue, the braces are used for grouping first, before the commands are looked at.

Comment: Actually, I think the rule is really as simple as that: in a script, every character after the # in the comment command up to the line break is ignored. The tricky part is to **quote the script** correctly when it's part of (an argument in) a larger script.

Comment: The way comments and braces interact is tricky if you're used to the way other languages do it. The trick is that comments are only ever detected as comments when the first letter of a command is being searched for; otherwise, `#` is a normal character.